# Running a java program from located on a network server.

Tags: java, networking, network-programming, classpath

I have a java application that is run using the following command:

```
java -cp .;lib\*;myapp.jar com.app.myapp.MyAppStart
```

The myapp.jar is in a folder that has the following files and structure

```
/demo
    /lib
    /conf
    myapp.jar
    myapp.bat
```

The myapp.bat contains the above run command so when you double click on it, it runs the program. Everything works fine if i copy the folder to a local path. For example if the folder is in 
`c:\program\myapps\demo` i can just go in that folder and double click on the myapp.bat script and the program starts.

The problem i have now is i want to copy the demo folder to a path on the network. I tested it by copying it to `\\London-server01\applications\client\demo\` but that raises the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/app.myapp/MyAppStart
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.app.myapp.MyAppStart
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: com.app.myapp.MyAppStart.  Program will exit.
```

It looks like it doesnt like the fact that the program is run from a network drive. I tried a different approach by mapping `\\London-server01\applications\client\demo\` to a local drive letter and that 
works fine without any issues. It only fails to work if i use the full network path to access the folder.  Is there any way i can get it to work without the need to map the network path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead using . (for the current directory).  Assign it to a variable and qualify the jar with the entire path to run it.

set MY_JAR_PATH=\London-server01\applications\client\demo\

java -cp %MY_JAR_PATH%;lib*;%MY_JAR_PATH%\myapp.jar com.app.myapp.MyAppStart

This might help!

Comment: Thanks - Using variables i can now run the application. The only issue though is that it does not find the 'conf' folder. It is in the same folder and it is hard coded as 'conf/application.properties' in the application.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this, This is the way I run my application. bit different from your one.

```
java -cp "myapp.jar;lib/*" com.app.myapp.MyAppStart
```